# How can I compare two documents ?(firestore onUpdate)

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I want to use the onUpdate trigger on a document to get the difference of the before and after.

So here is how it looks like before:
[image]

and after:
[image]

So in the example, the difference between the documents is "zfb5gXV54f5jbfn438Hd". With that, I'll use it else where in my app.

Here's what I have so far:

```
export const someFunc = functions.firestore.document('invites/{invitesUID}').onUpdate(async (change, context) => { 
    const previousValue = change.before.data();
    const newValue = change.after.data();
    })
```

So with onUpdate I'll be able to get the information that I need. What approach should I take for this? I have some ideas but wanted to know if there was a better way to do it. As always, I appreciate any help!

**UPDATE:**

So I came up with this:

```
export const deleteMember = functions.firestore.document('invites/{invitesUID}').onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const previousValue = change.before.data()['invites']
    const newValue = change.after.data()['invites']
    if (previousValue.length > newValue.length) {
        
        const prevInviteListArray = Object.entries(previousValue)
        const newInviteListArray = Object.entries(newValue)
        let difference = prevInviteListArray.filter((x: any) => !newInviteListArray.includes(x));

        console.log('old list: ' + prevInviteListArray)
        console.log('new list: ' + newInviteListArray)
        console.log('the difference: ' + difference)
    }
})
```

and got this result:[image]

Not sure why the filter didn't work...any ideas? (Also how can I see what's in the object?)

Answer (score 1):

You're already on the right track, the onUpdate trigger will provide the document both before/after the change. From there how you decide to compare both objects to acknowledge which changes happened it's completely up to you. In case you're looking for examples you may check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#writing_data)

---

The code `event.before.data()` returns a kind of Javascript Hashmap that you could access as normally would do and the same thing applies for array fields inside the Firestore document, to you they're just JS arrays. I made the code work as follows:

```
export const deleteMember = functions.firestore.document('invites/{invitesUID}').onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const previousValue = change.before.data()['invites']
    const newValue = change.after.data()['invites']
    if (previousValue.length > newValue.length) {
        let difference = previousValue.filter(x => !newValue.includes(x));
        console.log('old list: ' + previousValue)
        console.log('new list: ' + newValue)
        console.log('the difference: ' + difference)
```

Comment: Hey I made an update to my question, can you take a look at it?