# How can I isolate the data that has been created/updated within a list on a document?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am creating a function that listens for newly created documents, or updated documents. I am trying to grab the most recent item added to a Firestore document that is a `list` field. Here is my approach:

```
export const grabId = functions.firestore
  .document('Posts/{documentId}')
  .onWrite(async (change,context) => {
    const document = change.after.exists ? change.after.data() : null;
    if(document){
      // Grab most recent item from list on document
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  })
```

How can I isolate the most recently added item to the list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I compare two documents ?(firestore onUpdate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62805337/how-can-i-compare-two-documents-firestore-onupdate)

Comment: I haven't tested it but just reading the code it seems to be the correct answer. I ended up using some generic Typescript of a similar approach: `const missing = after.filter(item => before.indexOf(item) < 0)`. The code you presented seems more readable. @FerreginaPelona